# Centering a mini banner across various screen sizes

Tags: css

I'm trying to make sure this mini banner stays centered and responsive across different screen sizes, you can see in first photo it does (larger screen size) but in second it doesn't (smaller screen size)

[image: Larger screen size]

[image: Smaller Screen size]

My code is attached for css.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<style>
  .logo-bar-section {
    max-width: {
      {
        section.settings.logo_width
      }
    }
    ;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    /*     margin: 0 27.5px 30px; */
    margin-left: 250px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .whole {
    background-color: #ebf2ef;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>
```

HTML

```html
<div>
  <h2>{{ section.settings.title | escape }}</h2>
  {% if section.blocks.size > 0 %}
  <ul class="whole">
    {% for block in section.blocks %}
    <li class="logo-bar-section" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
      {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
      <a href="{{ block.settings.link }}">
          {% endif %}
          {% if block.settings.image != blank %}
            {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '150x150', scale: 2 | img_tag: block.settings.image.alt, 'logo-bar__image' }}
          {% else %}
            {{ 'logo' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
          {% endif %}
          {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
            </a> {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
</div>

{% schema %} { "name": "Logo list", "class": "index-section", "max_blocks": 10, "settings": [ { "type": "text", "id": "title", "label": "Heading", "default": "Logo list" }, { "type": "select", "id": "logo_width", "label": "Logo width", "default": "150px",
"options": [ { "label": "Extra Small", "value": "100px" }, { "label": "Small", "value": "125px" }, { "label": "Medium", "value": "150px" }, { "label": "Large", "value": "175px" }, { "label": "Extra Large", "value": "200px" } ] } ], "blocks": [ { "type":
"logo_image", "name": "Logo", "settings": [ { "type": "image_picker", "id": "image", "label": "Image" }, { "type": "url", "id": "link", "label": "Link", "info": "Optional" } ] } ], "presets": [ { "name": "Logo list", "category": "Image", "blocks": [ {
"type": "logo_image" }, { "type": "logo_image" }, { "type": "logo_image" }, { "type": "logo_image" } ] } ] } {% endschema %}
```

Comment: can u share ur html code ?

Comment: @gokhancevik yeah sure, just added into post

Comment: It would be better if you could share a code pen of it. But I think it's due to the margin-left  on small screen sizes. You might need to add media query in it

Comment: do you know how best to code the media query?